# -bash:: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted

Tags: bash, shell-script, java

I recently replaced adoptopenjdk-13 with adoptopenjdk-16.  I have a script file that uses the tool by name, so I changed it from 13 to 16.  Its new contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z ${JAVA_OPTS+x} ]
then
  # Set some defaults
  JAVA_OPTS=""
fi
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -jar $CROMWELL_HOME/womtool.jar "$@"

me $  which bash
/bin/bash
me $  ll /usr/local/cromwell
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  wheel   192B Sep 27 12:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x  23 root  wheel   736B Nov 10  2020 ../
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel   210B Sep 27 12:42 cromwell*
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    39B Jul 14 15:14 cromwell.jar
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel   208B Sep 27 12:41 womtool*
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel    38B Jul 14 15:14 womtool.jar
m082166@me $ $CROMWELL_HOME/womtool validate MyWDL.wdl
-bash: /usr/local/cromwell/womtool: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted
me $  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -jar $CROMWELL_HOME/womtool.jar validate MyWDL.wdl
Success!
```

Why is bash refusing to let me run the script, when running the contents of the script is perfectly fine?  This literally just broke after I updated the script file to point to the correct tool

Comment: Does the user have execution permissions to the script?

Comment: Also, another question. What is the EOL format of the script?

Comment: Everyone has execution permissions for the script
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel   208B Sep 27 12:41 womtool*

Comment: got it. How about the EOL format?

Comment: Lines end with \n

Comment: Is it possible that you updated the script using Windows end-of-line terminators? Does `head -1 /usr/local/cromwell/womtoll | od -c` contain a `\r` character?

Comment: Perhaps, this is relevant: https://malcontentboffin.com/2019/12/macOS-Error-bin-bash-bad-interpreter-Operation-not-permitted.html

Comment: m082166@R5191920 $ head -1 /usr/local/cromwell/womtool | od -c
0000000    #   !   /   b   i   n   /   b   a   s   h  \n                
0000014

Comment: Thank you @eftshift0 that was it.  Please make that an answer, so I can upvote and green check it :-)

Comment: @eftshift0 this is why answers, not links to answers, are preferred on SE sites. That link is dead.

Comment: Great point! Glad it had been done already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to elfshift
This was the [answer](https://malcontentboffin.com/2019/12/macOS-Error-bin-bash-bad-interpreter-Operation-not-permitted.html).  Apparently the MacOS decided to put those files into "quarantine", and so wouldn't let me run the files

```
sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /usr/local/cromwell/*
```

fixed the issue

Comment: Fixed it for me too. Strange, I use this script all the time, not sure how or why it got re-quarantined.

Answer (score 1):

To view the extended attributes of the file (my filename
is `script.sh`):

`xattr -l script.sh`

If you see `com.apple.quarantine` in the list of attributes, remove it using this command:

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine my-file.sh`

If you have multiple files, feel free to update the last parameter as it fits.